# Handlebars.JS is not replacing tags with context

Tags: django, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm having quite the problem with `Handlebars.JS` as it is not replacing `{{anything}}` with the corresponding variables.

I have the following helper function:

```
function compileTemplate(name){
return Handlebars.compile($('#'+name+'-template').html());
}
```

Which I use in the following Backbone view:

```
Soccer.Teams.Li = compileTemplate('team-li');

    Soccer.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "index"
        },
        index: function(){
            Soccer.container.html(compileTemplate('main'));
            var teams = new Soccer.Teams.View();
            var container = Soccer.container.find('.sub-content');
            container.html(teams.render().$el.html());
            var teamsList = container.find('#teams-list');
            teams.teams.forEach(function(team){
                teamsList.append(Soccer.Teams.Li(team.toJSON()));
            }, this);
            Soccer.page.trigger('pagecreate');
        }
    });
```

And `#team-li-template` is the following:

```
<script id="team-li-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <li team-id="{{id}}"><a>{{name}}</a></li>
    </script>
```

The correct information is definitely being passed, if I `console.log` the `.toJSON` it does contain the correct information, but nothing is replaced, the tags are just turned into nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Update:

Strangely enough I copied all of my code to a JSFiddle and it worked fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/vcrhh/1/

The actual app is 54.235.201.41 (sorry, wouldn't let me add it as a link).

Also tried just saving the code as a file locally and running it, that works fine too.

User username: mkremer90@gmail.com and password test for both. See anything wrong with the actual app? Why would it work in JSFiddle/local and not in my app?

Comment: have you tried not including the `.toJSON()`? or perhaps hardcoding in some values to see if it works, like 

    teamsList.append(Soccer.Teams.Li({id:1233, name:"asdfasdf"}));

Comment: @CheapSteaks Have tried both to no avail... :(

Comment: @MatthewKremer The Handlebars code by itself seems to be fine. http://jsfiddle.net/W8Xxf/

Comment: Added a JSFiddle...weirdly enough it working in the fiddle, but not in my app...care to take a look at each? Added links to the main post.

Comment: So I quite literally copied the page source from the JSFiddle and replaced my index.html with it...the exact same code doesn't work for me when looking at 54.235.201.41 I don't even know how that makes sense.

Comment: I don't know if it will help but putting your template `<script>`s inside `<body>` is a bad idea, that's just an easy way to accidentally erase your templates.

Comment: Um, you might want to have another look at your template on 54.235.201.41, I don't see any Handlebars in `<li team-id=""><a></a></li>`. Perhaps something is eating up your braces while serving the page.

Comment: @muistooshort Wow, can't believe I didn't catch that. I'm using Django to serve the HTML, so Django Templates is eating them. If you want to post an answer about checking conflicting template libraries, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel bad, the best place to hide something is right out in the open :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Handlebars and Backbone looks fine and the fiddle runs so the problem is with your testing environment. When I look at the page source on your server, I see this:

```
<script id="team-li-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li team-id=""><a></a></li>
</script>
```

Note the conspicuous absence of braces. I'd guess that something server-side is eating your braces. You say that you're using Django so Django's templates are probably causing your problem.